# hash as def argument

Tags: ruby, hash, function

Is the following possible in any way? I keep running into a odd number list for Hash

```
def thores_hammer(bling)
  hammer_bling = { bling }
end

thores_hammer :rubys    => 5,
              :emeralds => 5,
              :souls    => 333
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're running into an error is that the
`Hash` is implicitly created when the `thores_hammer` method
is invoked - so when you do `{ bling }` you're creating a hash
with only one key (which is itself a hash) and no value.  Thus the
error.

All you need to do is drop the curly braces:

```
irb> def thores_hammer(bling)
       hammer_bling = bling
     end
#=> nil
irb> thores_hammer :rubys    => 5,
                   :emeralds => 5,
                   :souls    => 333
#=> {:rubys=>5, :emeralds=>5, :souls=>333}
```

Comment: Magic!  Twice you have saved me

Comment: I think im going to spend more time in irb

Answer (score 2):

What you may be intending to do is make a copy of the Hash which could be done as:

```
def thores_hammer(bling)
  hammer_bling = bling.dup
end
```

It might be a good idea to make a copy if you're intending to use the Hash for a long period of time and aren't sure if modifying the copy the method was given is a good idea because it could be used in other places.

Also, there are several different uses for curly braces within Ruby such as declaring blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def thores_hammer(bling)
  hammer_bling = bling
end

thores_hammer Hash[:rubys => 5, :emeralds => 5, :souls => 333]
```